# PowerPoint VBA: Determine the XY Position and WH of shape when ROTATED

Tags: vba, position, ms-office, shapes

I am struggling with powerpoint (2010) VBA. I am trying to align two shapes top to top, meaning, that on the y-axis the highest point/side of the first shape should be aligned with the highest point/side of the second shape.

The following code is working for me, but ONLY when neither of the shapes are being turned, because shp.top returns the unrotated y-position of a shape, but not the rotated one:

```
' ==================================

Sub align_top()

ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).Top = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(2).Top

End Sub

' ==================================
```

Does anybody know how I can retrieve the roated xywh?